# Is there a keyboard shortcut to create a new file in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut to create a new file in IntelliJ IDEA or do I have to tinker with the [keymap](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html) settings to create one?

P.S. The closest I have found is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> but I still have to press Enter ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [reference card](https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf) for the default keymap does not show such a pre-defined binding, but you can easily create a [custom](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html) one in the `Setting` under `Keymap` -> `File`.

Comment: can someone please elaborate on how one would go about doing this? thanks. 

Answer (score 0):

yes there is press alt home to navigate to the directory then you can use the alt insert